# Jumps of FV predictable processes at totally inaccessible stopping times

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Can a continuous time predictable FV (finite variation) process have a jump at a totally inaccessible stopping time?

Comment: the answer is in the question any predictable process has no inacessible stopping time (or unpredictable stopping time) ...

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
By saying the process has no inacessible stopping time you are refering to hitting times/ jump times of the process? I was actually guessing this would be the answer but I could not find any proof of this fact, nor could I find it stated in any of the literature I have looked in. Is it because predictable processes are the ucp limits of left-continuous processes for which this fact is obviously true?
/B.R.

Comment: I suppose you mean stopping times w.r.t. the natural fitration of the process?

Comment: Predictable processes are those measurable with respect to predictable filtration which is in turn generated by predictable stopping times. I don't know a precise reference but if you search in George Lowther blog you might find enough information regards

Comment: I was unaware of this fact since I am following Philip Protters book on stochastic calculus which defines the predictable sigma algebra differently. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

No! it is impossible that "a continuous time predictable FV (finite variation) process have a jump at a totally inaccessible stopping time".
Please refer to  Jacod, J. and  A. N. Shiryayev, *Limit Theory for Stochastic Processes*, 2ed. Springer, 2003. Ch2, Prop.2.24, pp 22.